Show that $(n+1)^{p+1} - n - 1 = n(n+1){A_p}(n)$ with ${A_p}(n)$ a polynomial of degree p-1
With $${S_p}(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n k^p$$
I proved that  $$(n+1)^{p+1} - n - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \frac{(p+1)!}{j!(p+1-j)!}\quad*{S_j}(n) + (p+1){S_p}(n) $$
Now I need to prove that $$(n+1)^{p+1} - n - 1 = n(n+1){A_p}(n)$$ with ${A_p}(n)$ a polynomial
I tried : $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \frac{(p+1)!}{j!(p+1-j)!}\quad*{S_j}(n) + (p+1){S_p}(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(( \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p+1)!}{j!(p+1-j)!}*k^j)\quad + (p+1){S_p}(n)) $
If we write : $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p+1)!}{j!(p+1-j)!}*k^j = {A_p}(k)$
We have $\sum_{k=0}^n ({A_p}(k) + (p+1){S_p}(n))$
But here, I don't know how to continue

The statement is obvious. Using remainder factor theorem, show that $(x+1)^{x+1} - x - 1$ has $x$ as a factor and $x+1$ as a factor.  Since $ (x+1)^{p+1} - x - 1$ is degree $p+1$, so when we divide by $x(x+1)$, we get a polynomial of degree $p-1$.

Thank you for your answer ! Have a great day
